# Centering page content vertically

Tags: html, css

I know how I can horizontally center the entire page with CSS. But is there a way to vertically center the page? Something like this...

---

[image: Example]

---

Comment: I hope it helps you http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/

Comment: Great article... `.className{ width:300px; height:200px; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; margin:-100px 0 0 -150px; }` did it for me. Can you post this as an answer to my question so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a great article in MicroTut to do that http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/

Centering with CSS:

```
.className{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

Centering with JQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $('.className').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });

});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
```

And you can see a demo [here](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.zip)

Answer (score 13):

You can also hijack CSS's `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for this purpose. The HTML would be like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    display: table;
}
body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you want horizontal centering as well, then add this:

```
#body {
    max-width: 1000px; /* Or whatever makes sense for you. */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Some would call this an abuse of CSS but:

- It will work exactly the same pretty much everywhere.
- Requires minimal markup and styling.
- And CSS's vertical alignment deserves a bit of abuse; vertical alignment shouldn't require the hacking, contortions, and absolute sizing that it does.

References:

- [Flexible height vertical centering with CSS, beyond IE7](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/flexible_height_vertical_centering_with_css_beyond_ie7/)
- [Wolf in Sheep’s Clothing](http://css-tricks.com/wolf-in-sheeps-clothing/)

Comment: Thanks Mu! I've tried several ideas. The great thing about this solution is that, whatever I put in the body, it stays vertically centred.