# How to align multiple form elements?

Tags: html, css, web

I've no clue at design, and I'm trying to get a simple HTML form to look like this:
[image].

Basically, it's a form with *three* input fields and *one* submit button.

Regarding the input fields, there are *two on top* and *one below*. I'd like these to be perfectly centre-aligned with each other and the second one to stretch to be the same width as the ones above.

Regarding the submit button, I'd like it to be perfectly center-aligned, both horizontally and vertically, with the input fields, but be to the right of these.

I'm not too worried about it not being fully cross-browser.

Thanks for *any* pointers!

**Edit**: I'd prefer if it were done with CSS rather than be table-based. (I hear table-based is just plain evil.)

Comment: holy troll face migrated from reddit to SO ;O

Comment: A few days I posted a link to an excellent tutorial to center divs horizontal and vertically. Maybe it can help you too, but with your inputs, labels, etc. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282758/centering-page-content-vertically/5282841#5282841

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this with pure CSS? By the way... do you know specific dimensions regarding your input fields and the search button? I could probably do this a little cleaner if I knew some dimensions. Anyway, check out the demo...

http://jsfiddle.net/zxSFp/1/

### HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="fields">
        <input type="text" id="left" />
        <input type="text" id="right" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="text" id="bottom" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="search-button" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#wrap {
    min-width: 375px;
    position: relative;
}
#fields {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#left {
    height: 15px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#right {
    height: 15px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#bottom {
    height: 15px;
    width:309px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
#search-button {
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    top: 12px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Absolute *hero*. The top fields are to accommodate around 20 characters and the bottom one double that.

Comment: haha ok. well what i've given you is plenty of width. but you can additionally specify the `size` attribute of the `<input>` fields which controls the width of the input field in terms of how many characters are visible... I think :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a table. :) Here's the code ALL ready for ya:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle;"><input type="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input style="width:100%" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables, at least to me, isn't the best choice. A few links about it: http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html

Comment: Very true, tables solve this problem *perfectly* (if only CSS were that simple, at least for me!). However, I'd prefer if it were done with CSS.

Comment: Agreed. Even with forms I tend to stay away from them, unless there is a design issue like this...then its just simpler to go table. Admittedly, I feel a little dirty doing it... :)

Comment: In my setting, div didn't work.  i had to settle with table method.  it works beautifully.