# aligning form fields centrally

Tags: alignment, field

I need two form fields in each line both against ab imaginary vertical central line, with the labels preferably on top, otherwise on each end away from the centre.

The nearest I have come is in 
[How to align multiple form elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304228/how-to-align-multiple-form-elements)

but I need to place the fields in the middle.

can you help?

Thank you

qim

PS - I apologize if this is too vague but I only met HTML/CSS 10 days ago and I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it is helpful to you:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 100px;">
    Label1
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    Label2
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you need like this:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 100px;">
    Label1
    <div>
        <input type="text" style="margin-right:5px;">
        <input type="text" style="margin-left:5px;">
    </div>
    Label2
    <div>
        <input type="text" style="margin-right:5px;">
        <input type="text" style="margin-left:5px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. That gives me one field in each line. I need two side by side centrally aligned, i.e. next to each other in the middle along an imaginary (or real if necessary) vertical live

Comment: great!!! I take it that goes with the css from How to align multiple form elements?

Comment: Sorry, the message went by mistake before I finished. I tried to change the length in the css file but the field boxes stay the same. Also i need the text to above each line, not in the middle of the two. Alternatively, to the right and the left of the boxes respectively.

Comment: Sorry, once again. I've just realized the HTML code works without CSS. But how do I change the length of the boxes and the position of the labels?

Comment: Ok, I've got it working. All I need now is to space the boxes a little from the centre; create some empty space.

Comment: plz tell me where you want the labels and what should be the length of boxs.means labels in from of textboxs and textbox should be in center ??

Comment: Ok.Just add some margins to left and right. For example:<input type="text" style="margin-right:5px;"><input type="text" style="margin-left:5px;">

Comment: I'm working on it and it's coming up great. One problem left is the country field that I had with the <select> . Give a few mins and I'll come back after moving things around. Many thanks Gerry,

Comment: Starting to look great. Two problems. I write two labels to sit on top of each box but they join together...The middle invisible line does not seem to separate them. I tried the extra code you gave me but could not work out where to put it, It might solve the problem. The other problem is the country <select> I did not want to give it up, if possible.

Comment: ok, the new code separates the boxes, but not the text. Sorry, to go on!

Comment: @smith i have added a new answer please check.and please clarify what is the issue with country dropdown ?

Comment: Hi. the country drop is not a problem now. I can leave it where it is and invent a new field for the one that becomes vacant now. I have not tried your latest code yet as the previous one works just fine. For me, at the moment, my problems are resolved and I must expres my gratitude for your help.

Comment: Regarding the submit button: should I start a new thread? I need something simple to start with. Just an email to be sent to me and a database to be kept at the server (JustHost). I am new to this forum and everything else in general and don't know how much I can abuse the forum's heklp.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 100px;">
    <div style="float: left; text-align: right; width: 47%;">
        Label1
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; text-align: left; width: 47%; margin-left: 6%;">
        Label2
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; text-align: right; width: 47%;">
        Label3
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; text-align: left; width: 47%; margin-left: 6%;">
        Label4
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

or simply use this :

```
<table style="width: auto; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Label1
        </td>
        <td>
            Label2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Label3
        </td>
        <td>
            Label4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gerry. I have another problen on that page but mmaybe I should start a new post: i need to get my submit button to send me an email and create a fdatabase (in the server) to keep the data entered in the fields

Comment: Hello Smith.
what are you using as your back-end.Means are you using Sql Server or Mysql.And also please tell me more about your front-end.